# How do I choose a suitable martial art for me?

Tags: self-training

I would like /love to learn martial artsHow do I choose a suitable martial art for my self?

Comment: That's a really broad question... but I think that it does have concrete answers in terms of listing the criteria to consider. I will mull on this.

Comment: Start by reading http://martialarts.stackexchange.com/q/466/5961. If you are looking for more feedback, please edit your question to include more information about your goals and any significant constraints you may have.

Comment: @mattm: This is what the vote to close, duplicate is for.

Comment: Let us know: what you are looking for in a martial art, how long you are looking to train, what restrictions may apply to your training.  Otherwise it's like saying "Which direction should I walk?" No one has enough context to help you.

Comment: Ah. I thought we'd covered this one before...

But if that question doesn't cover you, perhaps because you have different circumstances, just edit that info into your question and it will be noted as potentially able to be reopened.

Answer (score 0):

The only feasible answer is, given whatever set of constraints you must consider (time, money, health, etc.), try as many as possible and then choose to study whichever art(s) you enjoy the most.