# I am 41 yrs old with no martial arts training suffering with osteoarthritis of the knees. Which martial art is best suited for me?

Tags: training, self-training

As the title mentions. I want to learn serious self defense skills while taking into consideration my arthritic knees.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

TY

Comment: This is impossible to answer - whilst 1 school of a martial art might be perfect - another school of the same art may do things differently (and what people want/expect from a martial art differs massively too). Find all the schools in your area and budget - request a trial lesson INFORMING THEM OF YOUR CONDITION. Go and try them - see what works for you and that you enjoy - instructor is more important than art.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What martial art should I start with?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/466/what-martial-art-should-i-start-with)

Comment: You probably want to stick with low mobility, no/low kick martial arts. For example, Wing Chun kung-fu or Southern Praying Mantis kung-fu. Maybe also Filipino martial arts (escrima / kali).

Comment: @Collett89
Ty

That makes sense , will look around in my city.